# Chrome does not trigger focus and blur events for document in content editable iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

I'm changing the iframe content while it is focused. It works in Firefox but `focus` and `blur` event does not trigger in Google Chrome!

```
var iframe = $('#iframe').get(0);
iframe.onload = function(){
    
    iframeDoc = $(iframe.contentWindow.document);
    iframeDoc.focus(function(){
        alert('focused');
    }).blur(function(){alert('blur');
        alert('blured');
    });
    
}
```

Nevertheless, Other event like `keyup`, `keypress` are working. Do you know what's the problem and how to handle it?

Comment: Is the iframe content hosted on the same domain?

Comment: @StevenV Yes, It's hosted on the same domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome the iFrame document doesn't have a focus or blur event, the window does :

```
var iframe  = document.getElementById('iframe');
var iWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

iWindow.onfocus = function(){
    console.log('focused');
}
iWindow.onblur = function(){
    console.log('blured');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AYeCF/)

Comment: Yes, I was doing that

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jquery.com/focus/, `focus` can only be used on certain elements (mostly form elements). You probably need to look into catching a click event from within the iframe on the `body` tag to figure out if a user is interacting with it.