# Collapse a combobox on clicking into different frame/iframe/frameset in extjs

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, combobox, frame

I have a webpage consisting of several groups of framesets, frames and iframes used one inside other. The rough design of the page is as follows:

[image: pic1]

Note that each frame here contains some more framesets/frames/iframes inside it. I have a combobox (extjs 4.2) in frame 3 which gets collapsed (if already expanded) if I click anywhere in frame 3. However if I click on frame 1 / frame 2 or any part of webpage other than frame 3, it doesn't call 'onblur' listener of combobox. I tried to attach combobox.collpase() function to onblur event of frame3, but no success. Here is my code (partial):

```
    field = {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: list2,
                forceSelection: true,
                pickerAlign: 'tr-br?',
                listeners: {
                    'focus': function ( combo ) {
                         combo.expand();
                    },
                    'blur': function ( combo ) {
                         combo.collapse();
                    },
                },
                collapseComboBox: function(){
                    alert('1');  // alert is put for testing purpose
                },
                ......
            };
        // this._window gives frame 3
        this._window.attachEvent('onblur', field.collapseComboBox);
```

At the end, I want the combobox to be collapsed after losing it's focus and clicking anythere on webpage. Can someone please suggest me the right way?

Comment: can you please show your HTML Code for better understanding ?

Comment: you can write a function to collapse combobox on frame 3 losing focus. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044153/chrome-does-not-trigger-focus-and-blur-events-for-document-in-content-editable-i

Comment: I was dealing with the wrong window while attaching blur event. Finally I grabbed correct iFrame and attached blur event to it. So the last line in my code became `this._window.frameElement.attachEvent('onblur', field.collapseComboBox);`. Thanks for help.