# How to use iframe with blur and focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

**I want to give action to iframe with blur and focus,**

The scenario of my code is,I written a android question in webpage,beside that question I displayed android phone picture,what ever the code written below the question,the output will be shown in that picture and if you are out of browsing area,the title will shown as inactive.

action should be infocus or outfocus.

for this command I am writing,

```
<div class="andr_app">
  <iframe src=" <%= request.getContextPath()%>/images/mob_empty.png"       width="400px" height="800px" id="iFrameUrl${questionId}"  class="mobileDisplayIframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

The iFrame element doesn't have focus or blur events, so you need to use the window.

```
var iframe  = document.getElementById('iframe');
var iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

iframeWindow.onfocus = function(){
    //focussed
}
iframeWindow.onblur = function(){
    //blurred
}
```

<sup>*Reference: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18044350/4206206)*</sup>

Comment: Thank you joe_young for your support.

Comment: Its not working,i am havning below commands too..still it showing inactive only....

Comment: 1) $(function() {

    $(window)
.focus(function() { document.getElementById('play_banner').value = true; })
.blur(function() { document.getElementById('play_banner').value = false; })

  })

2) var iframe  = document.getElementById('iframe');
 var iWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

 iWindow.onfocus = function(){
     console.log('focused');
 }
 iWindow.onblur = function(){
     console.log('blured');
 }

3) document.getElementById("iFrameId").contentWindow.functionname()   This commands also I tried

Comment: Could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code (including HTML) to show where it's going wrong? @santosh

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my answer,but not in iframe.
I change iframe  to object,

```
<object data="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/images/mob_empty.png" width="325px" height="560px" style= "padding-right: 85px"; id="iFrameUrl${questionId}" id="iFrameUrl${questionId}"  class="mobileDisplayIframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">

 </object>
```